# Learning Python after R

Tags: python, r

I just started to learn Python after I worked about  5 years with R. I'm using Spyder as people are recommending this IDE as closest to R and more friendly to Data Science applications.

As a transitioner from R, is it recommended to start learning Python directly with Pandas, Numpy and other libraries or you should spend time first learning the basics (like defining functions, data structure and so on). I hope to get some perspective from people who did this transition as well.

Lastly, is there a cheatsheet/web page somewhere showing the basic functions in data exploration in R and Python? like

```
head(df) # in R
df.head() # in Python
## or
summary(df) # R
df.info() # Python
```

Comment: check this out: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/getting_started/comparison/comparison_with_r.html#compare-with-r

Comment: Welcome to DataScienceSE. I think that the question depends too much on individual preferences. Personally I'd recommend really learning the language from scratch, it's not very hard if you're already familiar with programming. But maybe it depends also what you want to do with it, how long you want to spend learning it,etc.